# NGROK, can't assign port on URL

Tags: ngrok

I was wondering if there's a way to assign a specific port using TCP to the URL that ngrok generates.
i tried with config.yml file, it has this code but it doesn't work

```
tunnels:
  blueiris:
    remote_port: 5666
    proto: tcp
    addr: 123
```

it generates this URL: **Forwarding                    tcp://0.tcp.ngrok.io:18777 -> localhost:123**

the port of the localhost pretty much it doesn't matter. I wan't to assign the port **5666** to the **URL** **0.tcp.ngrok.io** so it can be: **0.tcp.ngrok.io:5666**

Thanks.